# writing NSDictionary into plist

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary, writetofile

Hi i am trying to write an NSDictionary to a plist in the documents folder, but unable to write , i am using the  writeToFile:atomically: method , which returns False. The complete code is

```
-(void)writeData:(NSDictionary *)dicResponseData
{
    // get paths from root directory

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contractors.plist"];   

    [dicResponseData writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];  
}
```

the dictionary contains 25 sub dictionaries in it .

Comment: You don't accept answers, so It's not very likely anyone is willing to even help you.

Comment: @skram now i will accept answers , till now i did nt knew the process.

Comment: It happens - you're not the only one. I'm sure you'll get better responses from now on. :)

Comment: Try writing with `[dicResponseData  writeToFile:plistPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]` and check out the error message.

Comment: @Alexander the method you specified i used to write NSData , but i need to write NSDictionary

Comment: Try converting it to NSData and saving it this way. One or more of your objects in your dictionaries might not be proper property list types.

Answer (score 1):

All objects in your dictionary have to be property list objects.

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are
>   property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber,
>   NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and
>   returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the
>   resultant file would not be a valid property list.